# Accepting an answer that doesn't solve the question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently asked a question on MSE and got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4850243/1251882) answer. It doesn't actually provide a solution to the mathematical problem posed but rather gives a practical workaround to use interpolation and numerical solutions.

The workaround  turned out to be very good and I've implemented it in my simulation. I've upvoted the answer as such. However, it doesn't actually answer the question I asked which was to express the integral in a closed form.

Should I accept this answer on the post and therefore leave the question without a 'true' answer? Or should I leave the question without an accepted answer so that one day someone may come along and solve it, in the meantime not rewarding the person who helped fix my problem?

Comment: This is entirely up to you.  You can choose to accept or not accept any given answer for any reason you like (the hovertext *does* indicate that you should accept an answer which solves your problem, or is "most helpful", but this is unenforcable).

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is entirely up to you. You can choose to accept or not accept any given answer for any reason you like. The hovertext does indicate that you should accept an answer which solves your problem, or is "most helpful", but this is unenforceable.

*I turned Xander's comment into an answer, because answers belong in the answer section.*